# Clip Text with Moving background

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I have found a great method to move a background continuously horizontally.  The effect I am after is to create the illusion of flame, so the background needs to move vertically.  Is there a way to do this?  I am using Elementor as the builder.

The css code I have is as follows

```
.mask_text .elementor-widget-container {
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -o-background-clip: text;
    animation: maskText 50s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: maskText 50s linear infinite;
}

.mask_text .elementor-widget-container h2{
    color:transparent !important;
}

@keyframes maskText{
  from{ background-position: 0px center}
  to{ background-position: 2000px center}

}

@-webkit-keyframes maskText{
  from{ background-position: 0px center}
  to{ background-position: 2000px center}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To move vertically all you need to change is to add a second value to background-position:

```
background-position: <horizontal> <vertical>
```

```css
h1 {
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 100px;
        color: transparent;
        background: rgb(203,8,202);
        background: linear-gradient(175deg, rgba(203,8,202,1) 0%, rgba(131,46,189,1) 35%, rgba(255,252,0,1) 100%);
        background-clip: text;
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
        animation: maskText 50s linear infinite;
      }

      @keyframes maskText{
        from{ background-position: center 2000px}
        to{ background-position: center 0}
      }
```

```html
<h1>My Text</h1>
```